# Android listview with navigate button... help needed

Tags: android, android-listview

this is my database handler code..

```
                    // Getting All detail
                    public List<Detail> getAllDetail() {
                        List<Detail> detailList = new ArrayList<Detail>();
                        // Select All Query
                        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_DETAIL;

                        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

                        // looping through all rows and adding to list
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                Detail detail = new Detail();
                                detail.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                                detail.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                                detail.setDetail(cursor.getString(2));

                                // Adding contact to list
                                detailList.add(detail);
                            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                        }
```

i need to retrieve these details in an activity class whose layout file looks like a list view with a button like this..

[image]

the button should be assigned the id of the database row.. which when clicked should go to another activity where the details of the particular row is view fully..

pls help me.. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Is this list view? or have you created your own layout? If this is list view then you have extended adapter class and from there you can write click listener of those buttons. But if it is not adapter then you need to write your own click listener and you need to supply that to every button of your list.

Hope this will help you.

thanks

Comment: no.. this is a sample.. i need something link this.. please help he in how to implement this..

Comment: ok if you are getting all the data from the cursor then we have cursor adapter and for that we have sample application in android SDK samples. Just look into it and you will get complete idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution myself by creating dynamic linear layout with button and textview..

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout3);

        final DatabaseHandler dbpin = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all tasks..");
            List<Task> task1 = dbpin.getAllTask();       

            for (Task cn : task1) {
                String log = cn.getTitle();
             int i = cn.getID();


             Button button = new Button(this);
                  button.setText("View" + i);
                button.setTextSize(10);   

                button.setId(2000 + i);
                int width = 80;
                int height = 60;


                TextView textview = new TextView(this);
                textview.setText(log);
                textview.setWidth(200);
                textview.setTextSize(20);
                textview.setPadding( 0, 10, 0, 0);
                textview.setId(2000 + i);
            }
```